# CSS fading top and bottom "borders"

Tags: css, background, border, background-image

Take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/wjhnX/

I achieved it with this CSS :

```
background-image: radial-gradient(#CCC, #FFF), radial-gradient(#CCC, #FFF);
background-size:    2px 100%;
background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
```

Is this possible to do but the simulated borders would be top and bottom, not left and right ?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjhnX/188/) (Some breathing space for your content, I've used `margin` there, just make sure that it will apply to both, `:before` as well as `:after`, so if you want to separate, declare margin separately for each, p.s - I've made colors lil lighter)

```
/* Using only background gradients */

.one { 
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.one:before, .one:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    /* I've removed the vendor prefixes, if you are looking to support older browsers
       then refer to older version of this answer.
    */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(147,147,147,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Explanation: 
I've used `:before` and `:after` pseudo having `content: ""`, so it creates a block, you can say a virtual block inside the element... and which is further set to `display: block`, just make sure you use `block` there else margins and `height` will have no effect.. and last but not the least am using gradients with `rgba` to control the alpha/opacity of the gradient which will fade on both ends

Comment: That's pure awesomness !

Answer (score 3):

you can make it with a seperator as well.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjhnX/4/)

```
.seperator
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#CCC, #FFF), radial-gradient(#CCC, #FFF);
    background-position: 0, 100%, 0, 100%;
}

.one { 
    width: 400px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's good too, but adding elements to the dom... My preference goes to the E.T. solution :p

Comment: why. my paint is better colored. his is too dark, not same.

Comment: Instead of using extra dom elements you can also use pseudo elements to prevent HTML pollution: http://jsfiddle.net/YG9Lj/1/